# Why isn't my managed file getting saved?

Tags: 7, files

Please save me from ripping out the rest of my hair...

I've got a "managed_file" field in a form; nothing special.  When the form is submitted, I run something like the following code to, presumably, catch and save it:

```
$destination = "public://video_posters";
$file_return = file_save_upload('field_poster_frame', array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg png gif')), $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
if ($file_return) {
     $file_return->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
     file_save($file_return);
     file_usage_add($file_return, 'my_module', 'node', $some_nid);
}
```

(There is more testing of $file_return to catch the other cases, and a few other things, but you get the idea.)

What's happening is:

- An entry shows up in the `file_managed` table that is correct except that its uri is `temporary://the_file_name.jpg` instead of, presumably, `public://video_posters/the_file_name.jpg`.
- The file was indeed uploaded and is in the indicated place in temp storage -- just not where I want it to be.

Am I missing something obvious?  Any things to check on?  This is really driving me over the edge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `managed_file` element handles moving the file into place and adding a file record, you don't need to save it yourself. The file module does all this in a validation function which makes the fid available in the submit handler.

So, for example, if your file element is defined with `$form['file_id'] = ...`, you can change your code to something like the following

```
$fid = $form_state['values']['file_id'];
$file = file_load($fid);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
file_usage_add($file, 'my_module', 'node', $some_nid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I see what you're saying, but it may not apply to my situation: if my brain were not so scrambled, I would have remembered to mention that this file is not getting connected to the content type in whose form it appears, but a separate content type instance that I'm then hooking into the one created by the form.  In any case, I tried putting your code into a _form_submit() handler where I could get at $form_values, and, while there is an apparent fid for my field, saving like you suggested still leaves the file_managed's uri as temporary://.  Sigh.  Other thoughts? :)

Comment: Have you added an `#upload_location` property to the element in the form? That controls where the file is auto-saved to, so if you set that as `public://whatever/` things should theoretically work

Comment: AHA!  That (the #upload_location attribute, that is) did it.  Blurgh; thanks very much!